# How do I "fix" the syntax highlighting in Appcelerator App Designer?

Tags: themes, syntax-highlighting, appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I installed the beta App Designer and I like it a lot — except for one thing. I use the Cobalt theme which looks beautiful editing XML files but when I open a file with the Scratchpad XML editor, the display is unreadable.

How can I get readable text in Scratchpad XML editor without scrapping my preferred theme?

PS: I don't have enough reputation to create tags for app-designer or appcelerator-labs, so perhaps someone with a more exalted reputation would consider adding additional tags.

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug. Stack Overflow is [not the right place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) to report bugs. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: I didn’t think of this as a bug, per se, but more like inadvertent terrible automatic colorization/syntax highlighting. Will do.

Comment: So that describes a UI bug ;)